# How to generate links with trailing slash in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, slash

I'm porting the existing website from PHP to Ruby on Rails 3 and I have to keep the urls unchanged.

I have the route:

```
get 'companies/' => 'companies#index', :as => :companies
```

In a view file I have:

```
link_to 'Companies', companies_path
```

and this generates the url "http://website.com/companies" instead of "http://website.com/companies/".

I want the slash at the end of the url. Is it possible?

Comment: May I ask? Why do you need to keep this slash? (it is not RESTful way)

Comment: It is for SEO purposes. The page with this URL is already exist and redirect in this case is not the solution.

Comment: I need trailing slashes for relative urls

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add this to your application.rb:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }
```

This way all routes will be generated with a trailing slash automatically, with no need to modify each link in your project.

Answer (score 23):

Simply do as follows:

```
link_to 'Companies', companies_path(:trailing_slash => true)
```

[Documentation here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about the `:trailing_slash` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! But maybe you know is there the way to make rails automatically add trailing slash if it is present in the url pattern in routes.rb?

Comment: If you know, please give me the solution here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486758/how-to-make-rails-do-not-ignore-trailing-slashes-in-the-routes)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any references, but adding `trainling_slash: true` to the route definition also works (and avoids repeating oneself).

```
get 'companies/' => 'companies#index', :as => :companies, :trailing_slash => true
```

This was tested with Rails 3.2.13:

```
rails c
1.9.3p327 :005 > app.companies_path
=> "http://www.example.com/companies/
```

Comment: Nice solution if you want to apply this to a specific route

Answer (score 0):

For rails 3.2:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:trailing_slash]= true
```