# How to make Rails do not ignore trailing slashes in the routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, slash

For example, I have the rote in routes.rb:

```
get 'companies/' => 'companies#index', :as => :companies
```

There is the way to generate link with the trailing slash (like "http://website.com/companies/"):

```
link_to 'Compaines', companies_path(:trailing_slash => true)
```

But I want Rails to generate link with trailing slash if it is present in the route by default:

```
link_to 'Companies', companies_path
```

Now it generates something like "http://website.com/companies". How to fix it?

Comment: The original question was here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486758/how-to-make-rails-do-not-ignore-trailing-slashes-in-the-routes). I have to keep URLs unchanged when I port existing website to Rails.

Comment: Did you mean to link to this same question?

Comment: It was the similar question but not the same.

Comment: Sorry, I meant this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482693/how-to-generate-links-with-trailing-slash-in-rails-3)

Comment: similar to this, answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12364020/445023

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need your routes to understand that there is a trailing slash.  It doesn't matter if you put the trailing slash to Rails.  It should respond either way.

If you want all of your links to have a trailing slash, you can put the following in your application.rb:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }
```

This will make all links generated by Rails have a trailing slash.  Now, if you're trying to reject any route that does not contain a trailing slash, then I'm not sure about how to do that.

Comment: The main reason a routing table should recognize a route with a trailing slash or not is that it might matter for SEO. If both slash and non-trailing-slash versions contain the same content and each returns 200 consider changing this behavior to reduce duplicate content and improve crawl efficiency. https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Answer (score -2):

How about implementing a helper called link_to_with_trailing_slash(name, path)?

```
def link_to_with_trailing_slash(name, path)
  link_to(name, "#{path}/"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want Rails to understand what I want if there is the trailing slash defined in the route in routes.rb.