# How to add a trailing_slash to all urls without in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing, trailing-slash

I've tried adding this in application.rb

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }
```

as well as having `:trailing_slash => true` in routes.rb

```
match '/download', to: 'welcome#download', via: 'get', :trailing_slash => true
```

But neither seems to work. I searched through rails 4.0 doc but couldn't find related info. What am I missing here?

**Update:**

I've tried adding

```
Rails.application.default_url_options[:trailing_slash] = true
```

in `filter_parameter_logging.rb` since this is the only place in the whole project where I could find `Rails.application.*`, but it's not working either. I found the line [here among the releases](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/) and I am using 4.0.4. Am I adding this in the wrong place? And I did restarted server before rechecking.

And sorry for the simple question but from what I've gathered isn't `trailing_slash` supposed to be reflected in browser url as well, if not primarily? Because this is what I need, to go with historyjs.

Comment: are you talking about the urls generated in your application?

Comment: @phoet yes, what do I do to have all `download` automatically redirect to `download/`?

Comment: I think you would want to do this at the web server level, are you using nginx?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have the meaning of `:trailing_slash => true` wrong.

All it does is add the / to the end of you path helpers. No redirecting involved.

Your routes will still respond to both with and without the trailing slash.

If you want to redirect all non-`trailing_slash` uri's like `/download` to `/download/` using a nginx http server you would do something like this:

```
rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

You would still want to add the `:trailing_slash => true` to your routes so your path/url helpers generate the the correct uri's (so user don’t need to redirect).

Comment: In the Rails world, contrary to PHP, all application logic is kept inside the application, not Apache or nginx configs. I don't consider this a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Trailing_slash** refers to a `/` after the name like `page/` not like `/page`.

You have given your routes wrongly.

Change it to

```
match 'download/', to: 'welcome#download', via: 'get', :trailing_slash => true
```

There is also other way to achieve this by giving a `trailing_slash => true` option directly to your `link_to` helper.

```
link_to 'Downloads', downloads_path(:trailing_slash => true)
```

Though this work in **Rails 3**,not sure about **Rails 4.**

For more details see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482693/how-to-generate-links-with-trailing-slash-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 1):

I am using `rails 4.0.2` for me it's working

routes.rb

```
       get 'admin/update_price_qty' => 'admin#update_price_qty', :trailing_slash => true,:as  => "price"
```

in console :-

```
     irb(main):003:0* app.price_path
     => "/admin/update_price_qty/"
```

routes.rb

```
   match '/download', to: 'welcome#index', via: 'get', :trailing_slash => true,:as => "welcome_price"
```

in console :-

```
   `irb(main):002:0> app.welcome_price_path
    => "/download/"`
```

But I've tried adding this in application.rb

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }
```

not working.

Comment: Do I have to see the result in irb? Shouldn't trailing_slash add a slash in browser address bar as well? This is what I needed in the first place since i'll need to use historyjs to detect url change. And I don't see any change with `:trailing_slash => true`.

Answer (score 0):

You may add this line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true }
```

If you do this, when you call a Rails path helper inside a controller or helper, the generated path will have a `/` at the end:

```
class ApplicationController
  def index
    download_path # returns "/download/"
  end
end

module PathHelper
  def path
    download_path # returns "/download/"
  end
end
```

If you need to use path helpers outside controllers and helpers, you need to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, but apparently, this ignores the trailing_slash configuration above:

```
class SomeClass
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def path
    download_path # returns "/download"
  end
end
```

In this case, you should add `{ trailing_slash: true }` as a parameter:

```
class SomeClass
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def path
    download_path(trailing_slash: true) # returns "/download/"
  end
end
```